# Send info from third app to mdm server ios

Tags: ios, mdm

I would like to send some info from my ios app to mdm server. It would be simple info, like lastDatabase loaded, etc..

Searching apple documentation about mdm I found that the mdm server can sendo info to a app using the command ManagedApplicationConfiguration. The app can acesss this information using the NSUserDefaults and the key com.apple.configuration.managed.

My problem is to do the inverse way. I thought to use the ManagedApplicationFeedback and then store some keys in the NSUserDefaults, using the key com.apple.feedback.managed, but it seems not correct because this dictionary, by the name, has the purpose of send feedback info, not general info like lastDatabase loaded, etc..

I would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: There is no general purpose method for an app to provide specific pieces of information to an MDM. You would need to look at the particular MDM to see if it provides an API with which your app can communicate.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you very much. I will check if the mdm server provides this API

Comment: ManagedApplicationFeedback is exactly this general way of providing ANY random information to the MDM server that the MDM server itself can then integrate to create triggers, rules etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the info via "com.apple.feedback.managed", but you are saving the info with "com.apple.feedback.managed" that can be query by mdm server.

For the MDM server query, you have to use the api:

> PUT https://yourmdmhost.example.com/mdm

For the api details, check this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/get_app_feedback